# Error in solving a multi variable equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have started learning Mathematica today. I want to separate Et from an equation and I have written the following code for it: (attached in the pic)[image]

How to get Et in terms of other variables? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Normal@Solve[en == Exp[-((Et - Ei)/(k T))] ni vth sn, Et, Reals, 
  Method -> Reduce]`

Comment: Thanks a lot man!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You used `Solve[eqn, cond, var, opt]`; whereas, the syntax for [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) is either `Solve[eqn && cond, var, opt]` or `Solve[{eqn, cond}, var, opt]`. Recommend that you avoid using subscripts or similar formats except in final display.

```
Format[en] = Subscript[e, n];
Format[ni] = Subscript[n, i];
Format[vth] = Subscript[v, th];
Format[sn] = Subscript[σ, n];

cond = And @@ Thread[{en, ni, vth, sn} > 0];

Solve[en == Exp[-((Et - Ei)/(k T))] ni vth sn && cond, Et, Reals, 
  Method -> Reduce] // Simplify[#, cond] &
```

[image]

Alternatively,

```
Assuming[cond, 
 Solve[en == Exp[-((Et - Ei)/(k T))] ni vth sn, Et, Reals, 
   Method -> Reduce] // Simplify]
```

Also, for this problem the option `Method -> Reduce` is unnecessary since the basic `Solve` can easily handle the problem.